# How can I make a driver hide something when its not in a specific scene?

Tags: drivers, scene

I'm trying to make a driver so that it hides an object in the outliner when it's not in a specific scene, but I'm not sure what goes into the RNA path or how to make a scripted expression for it
[image]

Comment: Why hide something that isn't there? It's not in the scene, so why hide it? Do you mean that if you have scenes A, B, C, you want to e.g. be able to hide an object X in scenes A and B if if it's not in C?

Comment: I want to hide an instanced collection. I have an Animation scene and an Environment scene, i then have the Environment scene set as a background for the Animation scene.
in the Environment scene I have a collection from the Animation scene as an instance, if its not hidden it will then be placed along the background and layered on top of the same stuff in that collection which makes it hard to animate since i cant properly select stuff or see any highlights around selection. so i want to make it so when im in the animation scene the instanced collection in the environment scene gets disabled

Answer (score 0):

If there is no property available, why not create a **Custom Property**? However, it seems that it is the same as operating the visible button directly.

[image]